# How to combine Read/Write Data Code for RFID tag?

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I have the two example codes from MFRC522 Library and I want to combine them together so I can at first read the data from the tag and then write something new on it by using the serial input. I´ve already tried but I cant figure out why it doesnt work. While it waits for an input to write on the chip the Serial Monitor shows: "PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication".

This is the code for read data:

```
* Initial Author: ryand1011 (https://github.com/ryand1011)
 *
 * Reads data written by a program such as "rfid_write_personal_data.ino"
 *
 * See: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/tree/master/examples/rfid_write_personal_data
 *
 * Uses MIFARE RFID card using RFID-RC522 reader
 * Uses MFRC522 - Library
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

//*****************************************************************************************//
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                           // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();                                                  // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();                                              // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Read personal data on a MIFARE PICC:"));    //shows in serial that it is ready to read
}

//*****************************************************************************************//
void loop() {

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  //some variables we need
  byte block;
  byte len;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;

  //-------------------------------------------

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("**Card Detected:**"));

  //-------------------------------------------

  mfrc522.PICC_DumpDetailsToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid)); //dump some details about the card

  //mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));      //uncomment this to see all blocks in hex

  //-------------------------------------------

  Serial.print(F("Name: "));

  byte buffer1[18];

  block = 4;
  len = 18;

  //------------------------------------------- GET FIRST NAME
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 4, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834 of MFRC522.cpp file
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer1, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  //PRINT FIRST NAME
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    if (buffer1[i] != 32)
    {
      Serial.write(buffer1[i]);
    }
  }
  Serial.print(" ");

  //---------------------------------------- GET LAST NAME

  byte buffer2[18];
  block = 1;

  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer2, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  //PRINT LAST NAME
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.write(buffer2[i] );
  }


  //----------------------------------------

  Serial.println(F("\n**End Reading**\n"));

  delay(1000); //change value if you want to read cards faster

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}
//*****************************************************************************************//
```

and for writing data:

```
/*
 * Write personal data of a MIFARE RFID card using a RFID-RC522 reader
 * Uses MFRC522 - Library to use ARDUINO RFID MODULE KIT 13.56 MHZ WITH TAGS SPI W AND R BY COOQROBOT. 
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 *
 * Hardware required:
 * Arduino
 * PCD (Proximity Coupling Device): NXP MFRC522 Contactless Reader IC
 * PICC (Proximity Integrated Circuit Card): A card or tag using the ISO 14443A interface, eg Mifare or NTAG203.
 * The reader can be found on eBay for around 5 dollars. Search for "mf-rc522" on ebay.com. 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);        // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();               // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();        // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Write personal data on a MIFARE PICC "));
}

void loop() {

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));    //Dump UID
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.print(F(" PICC type: "));   // Dump PICC type
  MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
  Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

  byte buffer[34];
  byte block;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;
  byte len;

  Serial.setTimeout(20000L) ;     // wait until 20 seconds for input from serial
  // Ask personal data: Family name
  Serial.println(F("Type Family name, ending with #"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 30) ; // read family name from serial
  for (byte i = len; i < 30; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

  block = 1;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("PCD_Authenticate() success: "));

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  block = 2;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  // Ask personal data: First name
  Serial.println(F("Type First name, ending with #"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 20) ; // read first name from serial
  for (byte i = len; i < 20; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

  block = 4;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  block = 5;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));


  Serial.println(" ");
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); // Halt PICC
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD

}
```